# Tile array, randomising order of elements each time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array

```
A = np.linspace(1,5,5)
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

and I want to tile it 5 times, each time randomising the order, to give me for example

```
B = myfunc(A)
B = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,5,2,3,4,3,4,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,4,2,3,1,4,5])
```

How would I best go about this?

Note, the first tile doesn't have to be in order, nor does it have to be randomised, either works, whatever's easiest :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simple implementation

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

def sampleNew(arr):
    out = arr.copy() # Copy the array to avoid overwrite
    np.random.shuffle(out) # Shuffle the copy
    return out

random_samples = np.concatenate([ sampleNew(A) for _ in range(5) ])

# %timeit returns 13.1 µs ± 68.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

I'm sure there is a quicker way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize this using a random array and [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
N = len(A)
out = A[np.argsort(np.random.random((N, N)), axis=1).ravel()]
```

Example:

```
array([5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3,
       4, 2, 1])
```

Intermediate:

```
# np.argsort(np.random.random((N, N)), axis=1).ravel()

array([4, 3, 0, 2, 1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2,
       3, 1, 0])
```